# How can I make a div box that is indexed over another one not block the hover property of the second?

Tags: css

Well i am not going to include any code in my question ,

I have 3 elements

the 1rst overlaps(higher index) the second and the second overlaps the 3rd..

the 3rd element is a menu button and it has to trigger an event when on hovered

but the size of the 1rst blocks the hover property of the 3rd.

So how can i leave the 1rst element on the higher stacking index order and have the

3rd fully "hoverable"?

Comment: You can't with css bacause you are observing a browser issue. The browser raises a hover event over an object, that event is always raised on a single, specific object, that one on top. All you can do is propagate the event to objects underneath by means of a script.

Comment: so it is not like let's say possible to "disable" the hover property of a div container ? and how is it possible to do it with script ?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot disable the event getting raised. All you can do is to ignore the event. When you want to propagate the event using a script yo have to write a function that is raised when the hover event occurs. Inside that function you check if there are other objects beneath the clicked position. If so you raise the hover event over those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` on the higher indexed div:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .over {
        z-index: 10;
        pointer-events: none;
        background: white;
    }

    .under:hover {
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>


<div class="over">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="under">Dolor sit amet</div>
```

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/4244437)**

#### Points

- This will make the `.over` div completely uninteractable. You won't be able to use any click/hover/whatever events on it. Nothing involving the mouse.
- IE and Opera don't support it.

Comment: thanks so much , that solved my problem !!! i didn't new about this property at all .. it is not even indexed inside my text-editor, thanks again :) .. so for IE and Opera is there any other way ?

Comment: @cursez: It was originally meant for SVG, and was implemented with HTML only relatively recently. Note that there isn't a spec on it on the CSS/HTML working drafts, so be on the lookout for browser implementation changes.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, however I don't understand that example. Aparently the hover event for the upper object is indeed received by the lower object, but why doesn't hoverying over the lower object outside the upper object work as expected?

Comment: @arkascha: Because their heights match. Note that I've changed the height for the `.under` element only in the :hover state (so that it's visible). Play with it for a while and you'll find that it works perfectly even when there isn't a direct overlap between it and any other element.

Comment: sorry if  I confused you with my example it could just be 2 objects.

Comment: Ah, right, got it. Great thing. Sad to see that it is only supported by some of the browsers. And apparently it won't get supported in near future by MS IE and Opera. Only Chrome, Safari and FF support it. So not a cross browser solution. Anyway: thanks!

Comment: So is it possible to overcome this problem in IE and Opera ?